# How to fix issue of zkemkeeper.dll realtime events inside windows service?

Tags: c#, windows-services, zkemkeeper

i'm setting up windows service and want it to sync the device attendance to SQL Server database using zkemkeeper real time event. **i have successfully created service as well as tested the service on my local system which run windows 10 and another one window 8 service work fine and sync the attendance record to DB server at real time.** Now after successful testing on local system **i deployed service over production server where service successfully established the connection with device but it didn't respond to Real time event** for testing purpose i have created winform app and run it over the server and find out it is working and listening to real time event but i need service to work properly not win form application any help will be appreciated  thanks below is my code !

```
public partial class AttendanceSyncService_405 : ServiceBase
    {
        public AttendanceSyncService_405()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        public zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass axCZKEM1 = new zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass();
        private bool bIsConnected = false;//the boolean value identifies whether the device is connected
        private int iMachineNumber = 1;//the serial number of the device.After connecting the device ,this value will be changed.

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            //var thread = new Thread();
            //thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            //thread.Start();
            WriteToFile("Service is started at " + DateTime.Now);
            Connect();


            // LoadCurrentMonthAtt();
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
            timer.Interval = 900000; //number in milisecinds  
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            WriteToFile("Service is stopped at " + DateTime.Now);
        }


        private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (bIsConnected == true)
            {
                WriteToFile("Service recall at " + DateTime.Now);
                WriteToFile("Device Status Connected at " + DateTime.Now);
            }
            else
            {
                WriteToFile("Device Status DisConnected at " + DateTime.Now);
                WriteToFile("Service recall at " + DateTime.Now);
                Connect();
            }
        }



        public void WriteToFile(string Message)
        {
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs";
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            string filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs\\ServiceLog_" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString().Replace('/', '_') + ".txt";
            if (!File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                // Create a file to write to.   
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(filepath))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filepath))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(Message);
                }
            }
        }
        private void Connect()
        {
            try
            {

                int idwErrorCode = 0;


                bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net("192.168.0.177", 4370);
                if (bIsConnected == true)
                {
                    this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx);
                    iMachineNumber = 1;
                    if (axCZKEM1.RegEvent(iMachineNumber, 65535))//Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
                    {
                        this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        WriteToFile("RT Events didn't registered at " + DateTime.Now);
                    }
                    axCZKEM1.RegEvent(iMachineNumber, 65535);//Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
                    WriteToFile("Device Connection Established Successfully at " + DateTime.Now);
                }
                else
                {
                    axCZKEM1.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);
                    WriteToFile("Unable to connect the device,ErrorCode=" + idwErrorCode.ToString() + " at " + DateTime.Now);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToFile("Exception :" + ex.Message + " at " + DateTime.Now);

            }
        }

        private void axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx(string sEnrollNumber, int iIsInValid, int iAttState, int iVerifyMethod, int iYear, int iMonth, int iDay, int iHour, int iMinute, int iSecond, int iWorkCode)
        {
            DateTime Attendancedate = new DateTime(iYear, iMonth, iDay, iHour, iMinute, iSecond);
            string row = sEnrollNumber + "," + Attendancedate.ToString();
            WriteToFile("Attendane :" + row + "  Marked At: " + DateTime.Now);
            if (bIsConnected == false)
            {
                Connect();
                return;
            }

            decimal empserial = decimal.Parse(sEnrollNumber);
            attInsert(empserial, Attendancedate);


        }

        private void attInsert(decimal empserial, DateTime Attendancedate)
        {
            try
            {
                WriteToFile("Attendance Entry Arrived for EMP-Serial :" + empserial + " At: " + DateTime.Now + " for Insertion");
                DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
                DataSet attCount = db.GetDataSetFromQuery("select Count(att.[todayCount]) as attCount from tblAttendance att where (att.attDate = Convert(date,GETDATE()) AND att.fkSerial ='" + empserial.ToString() + "')");
                int count = int.Parse(attCount.Tables[0].Rows[0]["attCount"].ToString());
                Boolean INOUT = (count % 2 == 0) ? true : false;
                WriteToFile("Attendane Count :" + count + " & In/Out : " + INOUT + "  Marked At: " + DateTime.Now);
                db.Parameters.AddWithValue("fkSerial", empserial);
                db.Parameters.AddWithValue("attTerminalId", "Time1");
                db.Parameters.AddWithValue("attDateTime", Attendancedate);
                db.Parameters.AddWithValue("attTgId", 3);
                db.Parameters.AddWithValue("attINOUT", INOUT);
                db.Parameters.AddWithValue("attEmpCode", "no need");
                db.ExecuteNonQuery("spInsertAttendance");
                WriteToFile("Attendance Inserted of EMP-Serial :" + empserial + " At: " + DateTime.Now);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToFile("Exception in insert method  :" + ex.Message + " At: " + DateTime.Now);
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Type This Code in Your IntializeComponent and it will respond to realtime events

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    Thread createComAndMessagePumpThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        axCZKEM1 = new zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass();
        bool connSatus = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(192.168.0.177, 4370);
        if (connSatus == true)
        {

            this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx -= new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx);

            if (axCZKEM1.RegEvent(1, 65535))//Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
            {

                this.axCZKEM1.OnAttTransactionEx += new zkemkeeper._IZKEMEvents_OnAttTransactionExEventHandler(axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx);

            }
        }
        Application.Run();
    });

    createComAndMessagePumpThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

    createComAndMessagePumpThread.Start();
    components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    this.ServiceName = "Service1";
}
```